# Using RowLayout does not give height to parent

Tags: java, gxt

I am using RowLayout for a container. The layout is having the Horizontal Orientation. I do not specify any height to the container. I expect it to get the height based on the height of its children. But GXT does not show the children of the container at all unless I explicitly specify height to it.

Is there a way to make the container to get the height depending on its children without specifying the height when using RowLayout with Horizontal Orientation?

```
public class RowLayoutNoHeight implements EntryPoint {
public void onModuleLoad() {
    ContentPanel cp = new ContentPanel();
    cp.setSize(300, 400);

    final LayoutContainer innerPanel = new LayoutContainer();
    innerPanel.setBorders(true);
    innerPanel.setLayout(new RowLayout(Orientation.HORIZONTAL));

    Text firstText = new Text("First text");
    Text secondText = new Text("Second text");

    // Here, innerPanel will not have any height. That is, I don't see the
    // text components in the UI
    innerPanel.add(firstText, new RowData(1, -1));
    innerPanel.add(secondText, new RowData(1, -1));

    Viewport viewPort = new Viewport();

    cp.add(innerPanel);
    viewPort.add(cp);
    RootPanel.get().add(viewPort);  
  }
}
```

GWT version - 2.4
GXT Version - 2.2.5
Browser- IE 8 and Firefox 7.0.1

Thanks,
Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

You have given your innerPanel a Layout which will only affect the widgets within that panel, simply add

```
cp.setLayout(new RowLayout(Orientation.HORIZONTAL));
```

after you declare your main panel.

Comment: Setting the layout on the main container does not help. It works only if I add the inner panel with specified height. That is using the code  cp.add(innerPanel, new RowData(1, 100). But my intention is to make the inner panel to take height automatically depending on its children's height.

Answer (score 0):

If you could do a layout(true) for your container, you will find your problem disappears right away!